# Slick Slider: align slide width to Bootstrap container width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, slick.js

I'm using the slick slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to display 3 slides side by side. The slides are centered and the active slides shows in the middle.

The website is based on Bootstrap 4. I now want the slides in the same width as the Boostrap container. So the active (centered) slide will be perfectly aligned with the other container elements of the site. The left and right slides should grow to the sides.

To be clear: he slider should have the full width. So that the left/right slides can grow to the end of the screen. Only the active slide should be aligned with the container DIV.

**Here's an example for what I need/want: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/BXzxgP**

And here's my code:

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  enterPadding: '60px',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container bg-light py-5 my-5">

  <h1>Container</h1>
  <h4>The slides should be the same width as the container
    <h4>

</div>


<div class="slider bg-light py-5 my-5">
  <div class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
    <h2>Slide 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
    <h2>Slide 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
    <h2>Slide 3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
    <h2>Slide 4</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
    <h2>Slide 5</h2>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container bg-light py-5 my-5">

  <h1>Container</h1>

</div>
```

I tried to give the slides a fixed width for every viewport. But that doesn't work because the slide width is variable.

Is there any other solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand your question correctly. but here is what i change in your code.

to align with other section i added a `container` class to slider div and change `slidesToShow: 3,`

```js
$('.slider').slick({
 infinite: true,
 slidesToShow: 3,
 slidesToScroll: 1,
 centerMode: true,
 enterPadding: '60px',
});
```

```css
.slick-slide {opacity: 0.2; margin: 0 2rem;}
.slick-slide.slick-active {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css">

 
<div class="container bg-light py-5 my-5">
 
 <h1>Container</h1>
 <h4>The slides should be the same width as the container<h4>
 
</div>


<div class="container slider bg-light py-5 my-5">
 <div class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
  <h2>Slide 1</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
  <h2>Slide 2</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
  <h2>Slide 3</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
  <h2>Slide 4</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="bg-dark text-white py-5">
  <h2>Slide 5</h2>
 </div>
</div>


<div class="container bg-light py-5 my-5">
 
 <h1>Container</h1>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the slider should have the full width. So that the left/right slides can grow to the end of the screen. Only the active slide should be aligned with the container DIV.

Comment: i found something there is a lot of work behind this checkout this codepen if it help -- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mNEjWN

Comment: Thanks, but when I test it with a container div, the width is not the same

Comment: with class container will not work you have to make modification in there calculation only to achieve your width.

Answer (score 0):

First:
Remove margin from .slick-slide class

`.slick-slide {opacity: 0.2;}`

Then disable centerMode, set enterPadding zero. Like this

```js
$('.slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerMode: false,
    enterPadding: 0,
});
```

Wrap your slider block with container class

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the slider should have the full width. So that the left/right slides can grow to the end of the screen. Only the active slide should be aligned with the container DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a div with class row and inside it put a col-md-6 col-12 and inside it put the slick div and the same for others.
I think that may give you result.

Comment: sorry, that's not gonna help :(